# Android bitmap.getwidth returns null?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to get the width of a bitmap after loading it and i am using this code where mybackground is an int that is equal to `R.drawable.background`.

```
background=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),mybackground );

scalefactorbackx=WindowInfo.Width/background.getWidth();
scalefactorbacky=WindowInfo.Height/background.getHeight();
```

So far it returns a null pointer exception on this line.  I have to be doing something fundamentally wrong for this to fail.  Tutorials online that I read appeared to just call the `.getWidth()` function and it was suppose to work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking that background isn't null before you call getWidth / getHeight on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bitmap may be incorrect. Otherwise try to simplify your code to see where's the error. Or just check out some web pages.